# What is an appropriate data structure for storing (samples of) a 2D function?

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary, std

I am looking for an efficient way of computing and storing the samples of a 2D function in my C++ program.

In order to be specific, let me start with the problem in one dimension which is easy and then explain why I cannot generalize it into 2D:

**The 1-D version is as follows:** We compute the samples of a function z = f(x) in the following way. We read the data from the input and corresponding to each input we compute a value of x and z = g(x). Now, we have a table of (x,z = g(x)) pairs. If for any given x, there exist only one entry then we have f(x) = z. Otherwise, f(x) = z1 + z2 + ... (where z1, z2, ... are the corresponding z entries for the specific x).

The above procedure can be implemented simply using a `std::multimap`. Namely at the first stage we just store the results in the map (with `x` as the key). Finally we can iterate through the map and if two adjacent elements are *close enough* we just merge them by adding their corresponding values. Assuming the complexity of computing x and z = g(x) is constant we can compute N samples in O(N log N) time complexity.

**Now, I would like to generalize the algorithm into two dimensions**. Namely we first compute (x,y,z=g(x,y)) pairs from the input and then set f(x,y) = z1 + z2 + ... (where for any fixed (x,y) pair, z1, z2, ... are corresponding z fields of the table entries starting with (x,y)).

The previous solution cannot be generalized because of the simple reason that one cannot define an ordering on 2D plane (indeed we could use `std::multimap<std::pair<double,double>,double>` but then there is no meaningful comparison to see if a  key `x1,y1` precedes `x2,y2`). However, notice that there is notion of *closeness* on the 2D plane: given two points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) we can precisely tell whether they should be merged in our output or not.

Well, the very naive solution is to implement a  2D linked list (sorted in each dimension separately) where there is a better notation of adjacency. But this at least is very inefficient for insertion and (beside many other difficulties) the procedure would take O(M^2) time (where M = N * N is the number of samples on the 2D plane we want to compute)

I wonder if there is a way (more precisely a data structure) who allows me to solve the problem more efficiently?

I am really sorry for being very redundant and rather vague.

Comment: Look at data structures used in geographical databases. Quad trees, k/d trees, r-trees.

Comment: is `std::multimap<std::pair<double,double>,double, Your_comparator>` OK?

Comment: @JohnSmith: It would work in practice but the problem is how to properly define `Your_comparator`.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy: Thank you very much. I guess what you have mentioned is what I must be looking for. Do you know any easy-to-comprehend resources so that I can read about those structures? (Wikipedia seems to be very informal and inaccurate).